# Error in glmmadmb(.....) The function maximizer failed (couldn't find STD file)

Tags: r

This works fine:

```
fit.mc1 <-MCMCglmm(bull~1,random=~school,data=dt1,family="categorical",
prior=list(R=list(V=1, fix=1), G=list(G1=list(V=1, nu=0))), slice=T)
```

So does this:

```
fit.glmer <- glmer(bull~(1|school),data=dt1,family=binomial)
```

But now I am trying to work with the package `glmmadmb` and this does not work:

```
fit.mc12 <- glmmadmb(bull~1+(1|school), data=dt1, family="binomial", 
mcmc=TRUE, mcmc.opts=mcmcControl(mcmc=50000))
```

It generates the error:

```
Error in glmmadmb(bull~ 1 + (1 | school), data = dt1, family = "binomial", : 
The function maximizer failed (couldn't find STD file)
In addition: Warning message:
running command '<snip>\cmd.exe <snip>\glmmadmb.exe" -maxfn 500 -maxph 5 
-noinit -shess -mcmc 5000 -mcsave 5 -mcmult 1' had status 1
```

Comment: It looks like one of the authors of that package is a regular here on SO, so I'm guessing @BenBolker will eventually show up and be of some help.

Comment: I think I may have solved it. I think maybe it needs `glmmadmb(bull~1+(1|school)....`, however, after making that change, now I get `Error in glmmadmb(bull~ 1 + (1 | school), data = dt1, family = "binomial",  :   The function maximizer failed (couldn't find STD file)`

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  Any chance of a reproducible example ... ?

The following simple simulated case appears to work (although `glmmADMB` with `mcmc` is **much** slower than `MCMCglmm` -- it hasn't actually finished yet for me, although it seems to be chugging along without complaining).

For this kind of simple case I suspect that `glmmADMB` is dominated by `MCMCglmm`, although it could be useful if you are dealing with anti-Bayesian referees ...

```
nschool <- 20
nrep <- 20
dt1 <- expand.grid(school=LETTERS[1:nschool],rep=seq(nrep))
set.seed(101)
u.school <- rnorm(nrep)
dt1$eta <- u.school[dt1$school]
dt1$bull <- rbinom(nrow(dt1),size=1,prob=plogis(dt1$eta))

library(MCMCglmm)
fit.mc1 <-MCMCglmm(bull~1,random=~school,data=dt1,family="categorical",
                   prior=list(R=list(V=1, fix=1), G=list(G1=list(V=1, nu=0))),
                   slice=TRUE)

library(lme4)
fit.glmer <- glmer(bull~(1|school),data=dt1,family=binomial)

library(glmmADMB)
fit.mc12 <- glmmadmb(bull~1+(1|school), data=dt1, family="binomial", 
                     mcmc=TRUE, mcmc.opts=mcmcControl(mcmc=50000))
```

Comment: Anti-Bayesian referees ! ? I wish I knew what that meant. I've got an idea - something to do with publishing research ? Sadly I'm still at high school, but one day..... Anyway, a reproducible example: My dataset is a bit too big to post but I will try to cut it down. To be honest I am investigating `glmmadmb` because `MCMCglmm` is too slow - but I'm also on a quest to try out all the packages for glmm that I can find ! This model is just the null one - I also have more complicated ones with 8 level-1 predictors and another with many more observations and random slopes for year indicators.

Comment: high school??? boy do I feel old, and inadequate (I can promise you I wasn't fitting GLMMs in high school).  In general `glmer` is likely to be fastest (but not give you MCMC-based confidence intervals), `MCMCglmm` will be a bit slower, `glmmADMB` will be reasonable for point estimates but *much* slower for MCMC results. Check out the package comparison at http://glmm.wikidot.com/pkg-comparison ...

Comment: Thank you - I am going to read the link after writing this. Yes, I found `glmer` to be fast but I need confidence intervals for random effects. I tried to write my own code to do a bootstrap with `glmer` but it took forever to run after I fixed the sampling to respect the data hierarchy (not even sure I did the sampling right - sample from schools first, with replacement, and then from pupils where the pupils are sampled only from those that "belong" to the corresponding school" ?). I read somewhere that there is a `bootMer` in lme4 but I had no luck at all even finding the function.

Comment: I've read the link now. It seems I will be better off sticking with `MCMCglmm ` - I have tried to run `glmmADMB` on a small subset of my data `data=dt1[1:100,]` but after an hour it still had not completed...but it didn't generate the error.